# 'Mock' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

After following the example [Mocking a Dictionary with MagicMock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-a-dictionary-with-magicmock) I have the following mock setup:

```
mock_writer = Mock()
mock_reader = Mock()
mock_format = Mock()
mock_option = Mock()
mock_load = MagicMock()

test_dict = {"Bus_No": Mock(), "Team_No": Mock()}

def getitem(name):
    return test_dict[name]

mock_load.__getitem__.side_effect = getitem

mock_option.load.return_value = mock_load
mock_format.option.return_value = mock_option
mock_reader.format.return_value = mock_format
mock_reader.write.return_value = mock_writer
mock_spark = Mock()
mock_spark.read.return_value = mock_reader

Driver(mock_spark).run()
```

And here is the driver class:

```
def __init__(self, spark):
    self.spark = spark

def run(self):

    partition_names = ["Bus_No", "Team_No"]

    df = self.spark.read\
        .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")\
        .option("avroSchema", schema)\
        .load("{0}{1}*.avro".format(job.SourcePath, os.path.sep))

    partition_columns = [df[x] for x in partition_names]
```

And then it returns this error:

```
partition_columns = [df[x] for x in partition_names]
TypeError: 'Mock' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What's the self.spark object you're referring to?

Comment: It's a reference to the `mock_spark` object. The mock is passed into the `__init__` method of the class where it is assigned to `self.spark`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that because `read` is not a method I should not be using `return_value` from `mock_spark.read`. Here's the change:

```
mock_spark.read = mock_reader
```